# Is there a better way to make this queryset using Q? django

Tags: django, model, django-queryset, django-q

I have a query which uses `filter` but I know there is this thing called `Q` but trying to play around with it, I am not sure how I can use `Q`.  I am not sure which one would be better but trying to know another way to do the query.

What I actually want to do is...
for my queryset return I have a default field and two input fields which are options.

let's say, language in default is english, there is a location and title field.  If location and title fields are available, make a query to query location, title, and language.  If only location then only query location and language, if only title then only query title and language.

I have done it two ways, one with filter only which has less code...

```
    postings = Posting.objects.filter(language='EN')
    if kwargs.get('title'):
        postings = postings.filter(title__icontains=kwargs.get('title'))
    if kwargs.get('location'):
        postings = postings.filter(location__icontains=kwargs.get('location'))
```

the above does work with using only `filter`

I am trying to see if I can do it with using `Q` but cannot seem to make it work

I have something like this at the moment

```
    if title and location:
        postings = Posting.objects.filter(title__icontains=title, location__icontains=location, language='EN')
    else:
        queryQ = Q(posting_language='EN')
        if title:
            queryQ |= Q(title__icontains=title)
        if location:
            queryQ |= Q(location__icontains=location)

        postings = Posting.objects.filter(queryQ)
```

can someone please give me a hand?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `|` is for ORing `Q` objects. You want `&` for `ANDing` them.

You could rewrite your filter code as:

```
queryQ = Q(posting_language='EN')
if title:
    queryQ &= Q(title__icontains=title)
if location:
    queryQ &= Q(location__icontains=location)

postings = Posting.objects.filter(queryQ)
```

However I don't see any real advantage of this. Personally I think your original code is more readable.

Comment: got it, I will then stay with my code but then also have your sample in mind as would be helpful.  Thx thx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood what Q is for. Q is mostly used in django for more complex query statements that require OR/AND.

So, you could do something like this:

```
postings = Posting.objects.filter(Q(title__icontain=title) | Q(location=location))
```

This will give you all the postings where title contains the title OR the location contains the location. It's not very useful in this context because icontains will fail with a Null value and return everything for an empty string value.

Q would be very useful if you needed postings for titles that used two different icontains

```
postings = Posting.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_term_a) & Q(title__icontains=search_term_b))
```

Comment: if this is the case...then how does it differ from `Posting.objects.filter(title=title,location=location)
`  This would return location AND title too isn't it?

Comment: Quite right. That was a poor example of & in Q statements. I've updated it.

Comment: somehow Q gives me the feeling that it only works better with `|` as it gives less code.  But still a bit confused >.<"